# Computing Complex[CReal] roots of a polynomial

Tags: roots, computational-mathematics

I have a type `CReal = (precision: Int) -> (approximation: BigInt)`. I have a `Polynomial[CReal]` as well. I want to get the roots out of this polynomial as a `List[Complex[CReal]]`.

With $z_i$ as the ith guess, $n$ as the degree of the polynomial, and $f$ as the polynomial, using this guessing method (or a similar guessing method like Muller or NR):

$$
z_{i+1} = z_i - \frac{nf(z_i)}{f'(z_i) \pm \sqrt{(n - 1)((n - 1)f'(z_i)^2-nf(z_I)f''(z_i))}}
$$

has two problems:

1. The smaller problem: A single iteration takes a long time. A lot of time is spent inside of the square root, and even more time is spent on comparing the two results of the plus-minus to determine which denominator to use.
2. The bigger problem: The output doesn't exactly represent the semantics of `CReal`. The output is still just a guess, irrespective of the `precision` it is given. It should be able to represent the root exactly to a precision.

My searching unveiled [ARCAVOID](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/%7Eakobel/publications/Kobel11-complex-root-finding.pdf): it sounds like it is designed to be used on `CReal` (or something easily constructable from `CReal`). However, I've been unable to locate a reference implementation, and I'm not even sure if ARCAVOID is the best option.

What's a performant way to compute the complex roots of a polynomial to a *known precision*?

Comment: Search "numerical methods stackexchange" for where and how to ask a question like this. First hit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286977/where-should-one-post-questions-about-numerical-analysis

Comment: Can this question be automatically moved? Or do I have to delete and repost? @EthanBolker

Comment: Moderators could move it. I can't . Delete and repost when you find the right place.